# How do I hide a Youtube Short Title/Info when embedded into Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, youtube, embed

I'm working on embedding a YouTube Short on our website. Ratio-wise, everything looks fine. But the title of the short, in addition to our logo and sub button, take up a lot of the frame.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7cGJ.png)

I know there are ways to remove titles/info from regular YouTube videos. Is there anything different for shorts? Thanks!

I've looked up some CSS for YouTube videos but they've not worked for this situation.

Answer (score 2):

YouTube Embed Options:
When you use the YouTube embed code, there are certain parameters you can use to customize the appearance. For example, you can try adding ?modestbranding=1 to the end of the video URL in the src attribute of the  tag. This parameter minimizes the branding, which might include the video title and other information.

Example:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YOUR_VIDEO_ID?modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Custom CSS:
You can use custom CSS to hide or modify specific elements within the embedded YouTube player. You may need to inspect the HTML structure of the embedded player using browser developer tools to identify the classes or IDs associated with the elements you want to modify.

For example, to hide the video title, you can try something like this:

```
.ytp-title-link {
    display: none !important;
}
```